# I imported an restore an database and It shows #1067 - Invalid default value for 'user_registered'

Tags: database, mysql, errors, phpmyadmin, wp-user-query

My database tables become corrupted so for fixing them I restored data and It shows an error #1067 - Invalid default value for 'user_registered' how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Look up `user_registered` in your database and set a valid value. This should be a datetime type, as described in the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description). Press CMD/CTRL + F and lookup `user_registered` to quickly navigate.

Comment: Its just DATETIME: Magical numbers problem in my database I edit it and It worked thank you for your comment man I appreciate.

Comment: No problem, please mark as solution if it helped. :)